# Is there a tool like phpMyAdmin which can be configured to access just a single database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-applications, phpmyadmin

Is there a tool like phpMyAdmin which can be configured to access only a single MySQL database in a server?

I cannot use phpMyAdmin because it allows access to all databases. A view that can allow a user to create/delete/insert/update tables should do. I remember using a software similar to this but dont remember what it was. It would also be great if its in PHP.

Comment: Anybody's used this tool called Sidu? Seems to be a really light version of what phpmyadmin  http://sidu.sourceforge.net/sidu/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a MySQL user with permissions to access only a single database, and then use that account to log into phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing that but PhpMyAdmin is protected by apache's basic auth which means the user needs the root permissions to the web server. I dont what to give them that!!

Comment: Do you mean PHPMyAdmin is protected by an additional basic auth (as opposed to the standard auth you can enable in PHPMyAdmin?) i.e. it's protected with two authentications (one for the apache basic auth and one for PHPMyAdmin?)

Comment: @RMN No, it doesn't mean that at all. Go read up on HTTP authentication and PMA config

Comment: i have nothng n my config.inc.php file excenpt for $cfg['blowfish_secret'] and when users log in to my server they only have access to databases I'm given them permissions to.  (They login using the phpMyAdmin login screen)  They do not need root access to do this.

Comment: I am guessing PMA was the best option. My question should have been clearly stated, I already had a PMA installed which was HttpAuth protected with just a single login. I either needed a new PMA install with its own access control or needed another tool like PMA which would let me define roles/permissions for specific users. Anyway, installing another instance of PMA was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

PhpMyAdmin will only allow access to the databases allowed for the user you log in as. If your MySQL environment is set up as it should be, nobody should have access to more accounts than they should. Most PHP-based MySQL administrator packages will work in the same way, it just passes the username/password you give it to MySQL and shows all databases that user has permissions for.

Answer (score 1):

[SIDU](http://sidu.sourceforge.net/sidu/) allows you to connect to what db you specify each time, of course, you need to have the access to that db first.

Without the chart plugin, SIDU is only 90KB, with chart 150kb (the font.ttf takes up 50kb)?

But SIDU does a better job than PMA? sure in most areas. But the export need to be upgraded ? well it does my export job anyway. good to have a try from

sidu.sf.net

I m not sure what your question, SIDU can allow you to connect to just one database (in the menu tree browser), but you still be able to access to other database in the SQL browser

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin can do this, although i am not sure how.

i guess the most simple way is to create a MySQL user with the according privileges and configure phpmyadmin to use that account.

Answer (score 0):

Check MySQL Ajax Table Editor (MATE) http://www.mysqlajaxtableeditor.com/